# Drop in GA4 events and traffic affter user_id implementation

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, userid

i have a huge drop in ga4 after implementing user_id in ga4 configuration tag (as user properties).

Interestingly, changing the reporting identity to device-dependent gives the correct data. Has anyone had the same? How to fix it?